# Android NDK Eclipse Build Error: Unable to rename file. Reason: File exists

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk

I am building an Android project using Eclipse and native code.  95% of the time this works fine, but every now and then it decides to give me the following error:

make:  [libs/armeabi/libnative.so] Error 1

make: Deleting file `libs/armeabi/libnative.so'

Libnative being the native library I am creating.  Sometimes running the build again works fine, other times it just fails again and again.  OTHER times it works for days.

What is this and how do I stop it from happening?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone has the same problem try deleting the .so file from your repository and commit that change. I do not know why, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be fixed by these steps:

- clean project in eclipse
- run `ndk-build clean`
- run `ndk-build`
- If it can't work, try delete *.so in libs folder and delete obj folder, then run above steps.

Hope this can help for others.

Answer (score 0):

If this is only happening when generating your APK, try disabling 'Build Automatically' when exporting. See my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20350339/249239.).

Answer (score 0):

A computer restart fixed this for me

Answer (score 0):

To fix the issue just change the `cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.assembler.base` `tool id` within the `.cproject` file of your eclipse Android project. This ID seems to be identical with that of the other project you have just built. You may have copied the project to upgrade and the same id appeared. I changed   1798454924 to 1798454925 and the error was gone.

```
tool id="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.assembler.base.1798454924" name="GCC Assembler" superClass="cdt.managedbuild.tool.gnu.assembler.base"
```